# Enable scrolling in a component when body overflow is hidden (angular 8)

Tags: html, css

I have set overflow: hidden for my **body** to keep the contents only inside the viewport and to disable scrolling. Body height is fixed.
But I have a *component* which should have the ability to scroll horizontally. 
Since I have hidden overflow in body, now I can't enable scrolling in that *component*.

Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your component style:

```
height: 100vh;
overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in style-sheet:

```
overflow-x:auto;
```